# Must the Nexus 4 be rooted in order to install custom ROMs?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, nexus-4

Do I need to root my nexus 4 in order to install custom roms such as cyanogenmod etc or just unlocking bootloader is enough as i have flashed my nexus with ubuntu 13.10 by just unlocking bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to root to install ROMs on a Nexus 4. Just unlocking the bootloader and installing a custom recovery (Such as [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/129) or [CWM](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.4.3-mako.img)) through `fastboot` is all you need to start installing custom Android builds.

Comment: This is applicable in all the devices ? Then when do i need to root my phone ?

Comment: @NateshR, this applies to all Nexus devices and most others. You only need to root your phone if you plan on using an app or tool that needs root access (Such as [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup))